# Firefox Profile userContent.css Javascript equivalent?

Tags: firefox

I am using Firefox profiles to automatically apply a default CSS file to all sites using userContent.css

Is there a similar function to allow a default javascript file to be run on all sites as well?

Answer (score 1):

The addon sdk's [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) provides that.

---

Update:

Since the SDK is longer supported you can use the webextension APIs
[contentScripts.register({css: ...})](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contentScripts/register) or [tabs.insertCSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/insertCSS)

Comment: The link is expired